# Getting a custom view to scroll in Flex 4.5 Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm trying to create a custom view (one that is not 100% listview, for example), mix and matching images and labels.

One issue is that when the label overflows greater than the screen height, the rest just gets off. I had assumed scrolling or touch-drag scrolling would be automatically enabled? How do you enable the touch-drag scrolling that happens naturally in list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrap all the visual elements of my View inside a Scroller - this will solve that problem

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" >
        <s:VGroup paddingTop="3" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="3" horizontalAlign="center">

            <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="right" width="100%">
                <s:Image scaleMode="letterbox" source="@Embed('images/small_background.GIF')"/>
            </s:HGroup>

            <s:TextInput id="txtUsername" prompt="Enter user name..." fontFamily="Arial"/>                       
            <s:TextInput id="txtPassword" prompt="Enter password..." fontFamily="Arial"
                         displayAsPassword="true" />

            <s:Button />
            <s:Button />
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
```

Comment: It's curious that the s:Vgroup tag has to be included or else there would be errors. And it looks like the whole layout has to be re-designed using VGroups and HGroups... *sigh*

Comment: And the Scroller destroys the actionBar and navigationContent? o.O

Comment: @ina The scroller shouldnt affect the actionBar or navigationContent, and I use all of them all of the time. If you want to post up you View class, it would be interesting to see what problem your having